# reactToPrint library printing generates blurry images. I am using a thermal printer to print the contents using react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-to-print

[image: Printed Image]

I have been trying to figure this out to make the printing text clear using reactToPrint library, but it's coming as blurry.
I have tried making font changes(font face, style etc) but none of them seems to work.
I have tried subpixel-antialiasing also, but it still doesn't improve my print quality.
I am using a thermal printer to print for a restaurant POS system developed.

When I print any content writing them in any text editor that gives me clear output using the same printer.

[image]

Part of code:

```
<ReactToPrint
trigger={(e) => {
    return <MDBBtn size='lg' className="me-2" color="info" disabled={printBtnDisabled}>
        Print
    </MDBBtn>

pageStyle={pageStyle}
content={() => componentRef.current} />
```

Can anyone please guide me on this? Let me know if anything else is required?

Comment: Hey! Happy to try and help (I think you were asking about this on GitHub previously). Are you able to show more code and/or a demo by chance? It's very difficult to help debug without seeing the code. Also, to clarify: if you print not using `react-to-print` it works ok, but when using `react-to-print` it is blurry?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Thanks for replying back. I was able to resolve it to some extend by specifying the pageStyle property very precisely in mm values instead of inches which was before.

Comment: That's great! If you want, you can answer your own question here, that way others can see how you did it if they run into a similar issue. It's a very novel/cool use-case by the way, appreciate you sharing!